# sort json ignoring blank values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I've got the following JSON data:

```
var json = [{ "name":"A", "value":"valueA"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES"},
{ "name":"Z", "value":"values"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES12"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES123"},
{ "name":"B", "value":"valueBS"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES123"}];
```

I want to sort the data alphabetically but keep the *empty* `name` values in the same position after the *non-empty* `name`. so the expected output would be:

```
[{ "name":"A", "value":"valueA"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES"},
{ "name":"B", "value":"valueBS"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES123"},
{ "name":"Z", "value":"values"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES12"},
{ "name":" ", "value":"VALUES123"}]
```

I've tried the following method

```
function sortResults(prop, asc, array) {
    arr = array.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
    });
    return arr;
}
```

and called it in the following way

```
var sorted = sortResults('name', true, json);
```

This does sort the array but the blanks are also reordered which I do not want. What is the best way to fix this?

NOTE: I cannot change the JSON data order from the server as I do not have access to it.

Comment: In an array there should be no hidden semantics besides the position of the items, but in your array obviously there is some kind of magic that gives items with empty names some kind of special connection to the first preceding item that has a name. I think you are better off using a more sensible data structure layout. Is there anything you can do about the JSON? It's a lot better to create a semantically useful data structure at the source than trying to fix a non-sensible data structure at the client.

Comment: @Tomalak unfortunately there is nothing I can do about the JSON I am getting as I am not given access to the  server to change the code. tired to contact the JSON provider and they said they won't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trying to do it by using **high order function**. Moreover, you can [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) your data in order to sort your field, and then [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the result.

By using high order function, your code will be more reusable. So, we will perform a **map** and **reduce** transformation.

```
  var json = [
    { "name":"A", "value":"valueA"},
    { "name":" ", "value":"VALUES"},
    { "name":"Z", "value":"values"},
    { "name":" ", "value":"VALUES12"},
    { "name":" ", "value":"VALUES123"},
    { "name":"B", "value":"valueBS"},
    { "name":" ", "value":"VALUES123"}
  ];

  //Create a generator function in order to sort by specifing key
  function sortBy(key){
    return function(a, b) {
      return a[key] < b[key]?-1:(a[key] > b[key])?1:0;
    }
  }

  function sorting(json){

    //Reduce my json data and start with empty array
    var sorted = json.reduce(function(result, current){
      return current.name !== ' '
      //Build a sorted array
      ? result.concat(current).sort(sortBy('name'))
      //Return current sorted array
      : result
    }, []);

    return json.map(function(elm, index, self){
      return elm.name !== ' '
      //Retrieve the first element of sorted array by shifting it
      ? sorted.shift()
      //Then, retrieve current elm in json array
      : elm
    });

  }

  console.log(sorting(json));
```

Comment: managed to get what i wanted with this. just edited it a little to make it work. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your JSON by checking *blank names*.

1. Take the index position.
2. Remove it from JSON array.
3. Sort remaining JSON array.
4. Push blank values in respective index positions.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider **grouping** the values by adding a third field prior to sorting.

e.g. Start the group at 0, loop over the array setting the group field, increment it when you detect the next non-blank.

Then i guess you could apply a second sort (by group) after the first sort.